# I want to make drop down elements compulsory but unable to do so in php file

Tags: php

I want to make it compulsory for user to select one of the option in city , if he will not select the drop down option , the form will not submitted. But it is not happening...following is the code... request you to please help... will be of great help.. thanks..

```
                           <label>Your City</label>

                            <select name="c_city"  class="form-control" required>

                          <option > Select City </option>
                          <option  value="Delhi/NCR" > Delhi/NCR </option>
                          <option  value="Chennai" > Chennai </option>
                          <option value="Mumbai" > Mumbai </option>
                          <option value="Bangalore" > Bangalore </option>
                          <option value="Hyderabad" > Hyderabad </option>

                      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you need to change the **Select City** into a null value for the required to work:

```
<option value=""> Select City </option>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. it is working fine now.. i am very greatful to you..... thanks once again.